# Ballerina dependencies are resolved for the latest available than what specified in Ballerina.toml

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a Ballerina project built on Ballerina U4 (2201.4.1). The Ballerina.toml for this project as follows.

```ini
[package]
org = "anjana"
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
distribution = "2201.4.1"

[[dependency]]
org="wso2healthcare"
name="healthcare.fhir.r4"
version="0.1.17"
```

As mentioned in the above toml code, the project has a dependency for `wso2healthcare/healthcare.fhir.r4:0.1.17`.

This `wso2healthcare/healthcare.fhir.r4` package  has a latest release for version 0.1.18. Both the versions 0.1.17 and 0.1.18
are built on Ballerina U4.

**Issue/Concern**

The concern is, though I have specified `wso2healthcare/healthcare.fhir.r4:0.1.17` in the `Ballerina.toml`, it has pulled
the `wso2healthcare/healthcare.fhir.r4:0.1.18` from Ballerina Central, as mentioned in below `Dependencies.toml` snippet.

```ini
[[package]]
org = "wso2healthcare"
name = "healthcare.fhir.r4"
version = "0.1.18"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "constraint"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "http"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jwt"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "lang.value"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "log"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "regex"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "time"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "uuid"},
    {org = "wso2healthcare", name = "healthcare.base"}
]
```

This persists even the project is rebuilt deleting the `Dependencies.toml` as well. The behavior seems to be is that Ballerina compiler is pulling latest version of
dependencies that are available for a given Ballerina distribution.

But in my case, I have specified to use an old version of the dependency purposefully and yet it resolves  to the latest.

It seems to be bit misleading when the project is resolving a different version of a dependency than the version which the developer has specified in `Ballerina.toml`.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The version specified in the `Ballerina.toml` file is considered the minimum required version (https://ballerina.io/learn/manage-dependencies/#update-dependency-versions). So if there are any higher versions, it will always resolve to that.

If the `Dependencies.toml` file had the versions you required, you could use the sticky option to stick to the versions in the Dependencies.toml file (https://ballerina.io/learn/manage-dependencies/#achieve-reproducible-builds).
Otherwise, you may have to pull it manually and run the build with `--offline`